# ubuntu create a tensorflow worker node

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I am using tensorflow with python under Ubuntu

I read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) about how to start working with a tensorflow cluster, i wish to setup another few machines to run tf and create a working cluster, and can't find any straight forward examples for how to set up machines as tf worker nodes.

should i set it up on stand alone machines and then bind them all to a cluster? 
should i set up a cluster (if so, then please refer to some example) and then install tf on the cluster as a cluster?

EDIT: 
The answers are good and eligible, i am looking to understand the way that tf cluster concept will interact with the Beowulf cluster consent and if i need the Beowulf cluster in any way here

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the content at bottom of the page on how to run tensorflow as parameter server or workers, here are two parameter servers and two workers. The job_name says whether it's a parameter server or worker and the task_index tells the index of the machine in that group:

```
# On ps0.example.com:
$ python trainer.py \
     --ps_hosts=ps0.example.com:2222,ps1.example.com:2222 \
     --worker_hosts=worker0.example.com:2222,worker1.example.com:2222 \
     --job_name=ps --task_index=0
# On ps1.example.com:
$ python trainer.py \
     --ps_hosts=ps0.example.com:2222,ps1.example.com:2222 \
     --worker_hosts=worker0.example.com:2222,worker1.example.com:2222 \
     --job_name=ps --task_index=1
# On worker0.example.com:
$ python trainer.py \
     --ps_hosts=ps0.example.com:2222,ps1.example.com:2222 \
     --worker_hosts=worker0.example.com:2222,worker1.example.com:2222 \
     --job_name=worker --task_index=0
# On worker1.example.com:
$ python trainer.py \
     --ps_hosts=ps0.example.com:2222,ps1.example.com:2222 \
     --worker_hosts=worker0.example.com:2222,worker1.example.com:2222 \
     --job_name=worker --task_index=1
```

Comment: so this code is doing all the work, including setting up the worker node as a worker node and activating the local host with the correct port being open? don't i need to set the connection between the different machines? passwords, ports, etc? does it count on a cluster already being set up? my machines are two machines on one network with no other connection between the two of them.

Comment: Yeah, it does setup the port and network. I think you have to enable the machines so that each machine can login to another machine without requiring a password. I do this by copying my ssh public key to all machines from all machines so that login from one machine to another machine using ssh does not require password.

Comment: So i dont need to set up a beuwolf cluster for tf to eun on parallel? What is the beuwolf cluster usefull here for?

Comment: I don't think you need to set up the beuwolf cluster, though I have only tried it running on a cluster. Give it a try. I think the only condition required is that each machine could be logged in from all other machines without required to enter password.

Comment: i am looking to do it on more than 1-2 computers and looking for a way to run something on a cluster - once, and make all the worker nodes to co operate